# Ошибка Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type при использовании функции Sort()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Использую redux-toolkit, вот моя функция сортировки:

```
sortedPosts(state,action:PayloadAction<string>) {
        state.filterPosts = state.posts.sort((a,b) => a[action.payload].localeCompare(b[action.payload]))
    }
```

ts ругается, подчеркивая a[action.payload] и b[action.payload]: **"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WritableDraft'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'WritableDraft'"**

Что можно сделать, что-бы исправить проблему?

```
interface PostsState {
    posts: IPosts[];
    filterPosts: IPosts[];
    isLoading: boolean;
    error: string;
}

const initialState: PostsState = {
    posts:[],
    filterPosts:[],
    isLoading: false,
    error: ''
}

export const postSlice = createSlice({
name: 'posts',
initialState,
reducers: {
    addPost(state, action:PayloadAction<IPosts>) {
        state.filterPosts.unshift(action.payload)
    },
    removePost(state, action:PayloadAction<number>) {
        state.filterPosts = state.filterPosts.filter(post => post.id !== action.payload)
    },
    searchPosts(state, action:PayloadAction<string>) {
        state.filterPosts = state.posts.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload))
    },
    sortedPosts(state,action:PayloadAction<string>) {
        state.filterPosts = state.posts.sort((a,b) => a[action.payload].localeCompare(b[action.payload]))
    }
},
extraReducers: {
    [fetchPosts.fulfilled.type]:(state, action:PayloadAction<IPosts[]>) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.error = '';
        state.posts = action.payload;
        state.filterPosts = action.payload;
    },
    [fetchPosts.pending.type]:(state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
    },
    [fetchPosts.rejected.type]:(state,action:PayloadAction<string>) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
    }
}
})

export interface IPosts {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    body: string
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш тип **WritableDraft**, ругается то на него

Comment: Я даже не понимаю что это за WritableDraft, добавил в вопрос весь свой slice

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу тип **IPosts**, т.к. **posts** и **filterPosts** имеют тип **IPosts[]**

Comment: Добавил тип IPosts

Comment: у тебя может упасть сорт, если в payload придет `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш IPost индекс

```
interface IPosts {
    [index: string]: string | number
    id: number,
    title: string,
    body: string
}
```

И callBack функции метода .sort надо будет добавить проверку, что тип данных по переданному ключу это строка

```
state.posts.sort((a, b) => {
    if (typeof a[s] === 'string' && typeof b[s] === 'string')
    return a[s].localeCompare(b[s])
    return 0
})
```

Comment: Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'number'
Вот такая ошибка появляется

Comment: @SmetanFf Похоже что то не дописали. Вот [тут ошибок нет](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUD2BnM3kDeAUMqcgNqgAmEAHgFzK5SgDmAuo828gD7IgArgFsARtBJlgVRkLHQANJNJhgYADYQuYFiFZKyyUZioBPbbtZEAvkSKhIsRClQBhOFCqFlyAA44wRgwA7HJ2GzsETBBcZFpkAF4KAmRVDS1kAHIARkyFZGlGbPzjM0ZMgCZM63yUtM1yqvzC5GKjE3MsqprCVLUGrIBmPIKZVpKOxurwqJiwZE63Dy8k4kN-XEZaCKJZ2PwkzPqITIBuO1MAOg2wS+xMKDAACie4EoBKRIA+b0NgGGQTzApl8EEwALg5Gw7ESCUO3D0mWQADJkakQWCAaIoTC4fCdGxMu8fFAIGBBFAQMhIdDLupMAg4JpXJhhL4PBAntjocTDKTyZTkAAGHzWYlAA)

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html), позволяющий получить перечисление ключей из типа. Это позволит использовать переменную в качестве ключа.

```
sortedPosts(state,action:PayloadAction<keyof IPosts>) {
```

однако в этом случае возникает проблема в использовании `localeCompare`, который есть только у строк, однако в классе `IPosts` есть поле `id` с типом `number`.

Это пример показывающий как можно найти ошибку в типах.

Если гарантируется, что `id` не будет передан в эту функцию, можно указать это в типе, с помощью [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)

```
Exclude<keyof IPosts, 'id'>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=40&pln=18&pc=67#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZMGUxyTIDeAUMhcgA5Y4BcyAkhtpgNoC6A3OZTMABtIUFvSaj23XhWCYAMujgATUAHMGAI3ToBEOCB6Vk0KOigNsUNTwC+pUgnQhsyUMDDA4A-IQgMJPkQAvCTS1LSYdJwANGH8QtASURyxRrIKymoM8AKYEKmUJmYMAOQlpHakYACeVCiocNUCikoAgggeTgA8ACoAfMghZEZUjc3KDD22pDAAriAdwE7ImGZgogAUiJ0gdA1NLe07XQCiAB4IArNKEF0A1hDV6DDiEdHIJcBKJX19AJShNweLyBCAAOhorDBqygYA2W2iGgBQQGcDY2yWIAhYxaHDBzQQXggAGF0ABbUZQCAbDToxZObEHZQcP5-Cr2UgQM40WGucDQeBIV6sUJpJQMECzMkaaAFCgeMC6CxgKwgVRy5BaJTVZWq1QVIA)

Либо сделать тип только со строковыми полями:

```
type StringProps<T> = {[key in keyof T as T[key] extends string ? key:never]: T[key]}

action:PayloadAction<keyof StringProps<IPosts>>
```

В этом случае typescript сможет проверить, что полученное значение точно будет `string`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZMGUxyTIDeAUMhcgA5Y4BcyAkhtpgNoC6A3OZTMABtIUFvSaj23XhWCYAMujgATUAHMGAI3ToBEOCB6Vk0KOigNsUNTwC+pUgnQhsyUMDDA4A-IQgMJPkQAvCTS1LSYdJwANGH8QtASURyxRrIKymoM8AKYEKmUJmYMAOQlpHakYACeVCj4ViCqqKZUmAA8ACoAfMghxGwA1hDVriDIw9XoMMidyHCYs0MjHMYAHpAgSouWasgA-BMjdCAQAG7QHAydy9UclTV1aHDVAopKAIIIHk5dvf1hKgvN7Ka62UgwACuIG+wCcyEwZjAogAFIgfiA6Khge8vhj2pNpsgGmoWug2u1mBFut0AJShNIgdyebwESAAOhorHZiKgYBRaOiGnpQV6cDY6LhIE5OOUHHZbwQXggAGF0ABbIFQCAojQS2FOGWvd4cWm0ir2UgQNY0PljYTwJDiCIMyjAJQMECQ9UaaAFCgeMC6CxgRqqf3ILRKaohsMVIA)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Grundy и SwaD за варианты, в итоге получилось вот так:

```
sortedPosts(state,action:PayloadAction<'title' | 'body'>) {
        state.filterPosts = state.posts.sort((a, b) => {
            if (typeof a[action.payload] === 'string' && typeof b[action.payload] === 'string')
            return a[action.payload].localeCompare(b[action.payload])
            return 0
        })
    }
```

Сам компонент сортировки (и поиска)

```
const PostFilter:FC = () => {

const [query, setQuery] = useState<string>('');
const [sort, setSort] = useState<string>('');

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(searchPosts(query));
    console.log('поиск!!!')
},[query])

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(sortedPosts(sort as 'title' | 'body'));
    console.log('сортировка')
},[sort])

return (
    <div className='postFilter'>
        <MyInput
            value={query}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            placeholder='Поиск...'
            type='text'/>
        <MySelect
            value={sort}
            onChange={e => setSort(e.target.value)}
            defaultValue='сортировка'
            options={[
                {value: 'title', name: 'По названию'},
                {value: 'body', name: 'По описанию'}
            ]}/>
    </div>
)
```

}

Если я оставляю action в таком виде: `action:PayloadAction<string>`, то LocaleCompare выдает ошибку: Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'number'

Поэтому я оставляю литеральные типы по которым буду сортировать: `action:PayloadAction<'title' | 'body'>`

В этом случае уже внутри самого компонента в блоке кода:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(sortedPosts(sort));
    console.log('сортировка')
},[sort])
```

Подчеркивается sort и ошибка: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"title" | "body"
Поэтому мне приходится приводить его к типам: `dispatch(sortedPosts(sort as 'title' | 'body'));`

Выглядит костыльненько...